# Device Management is missing in ios settings

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build my project in Xcode and its working great but at the end Im getting an alert saying :

> Verify the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. Open Settings on Artium's iphone and navigate to General -> Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.

and when Im going through the setting the `Device Management` option is missing.

Note that it happend after I deleted the project from my phone and rebuild it.

I checked through preferences and I am logged in to my profile in Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Same bug on iOS 12.0.1 :-(

Answer (score 16):

yup... I had exactly the same issue just now...
you can fix it by removing the profile from xcode.. just go to `window` -> `devices` -> right click on the device and click -> `show provisioning profiles` -> remove all profiles.
The profiles will be recreated again when you run the app again on your phone...

Comment: How can Apple implement such a hidden feature? Why don't they put a button for that? Really bad software!

Comment: I am unable to remove them with the minus button.

Comment: then you have to reset your phone I guess :)

Comment: this should be the best answer so far

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me (XCode 10) when I did the following 2 things:

1. I disconnected the iPhone, then went into Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy. Then I reconnected and clicked "Trust this device" on both the Mac and the iPhone (i.e. the popups that come up when the iPhone is reconnected).
2. Reinstalled the app I had originally manually deleted from the iPhone.

Comment: This cost me a day. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to install application in the first place, but this method worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me! I assume this bug was caused by the same computer (e.g. your laptop) building different apps with different provisioning profiles and installing onto your phone.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem today. It appears to be an Apple bug that occurs when you manually delete all apps on your device attached to the same developer account.

An easy work around is to create a completely new Hello World app and deploy it to your device. When the "Developer App certificate" message pops up then you can proceed to settings and trust your account again and Viola! Your other apps will start working again.

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer! Thank you very much.

Comment: This answer just saved me with the new iPhone 15. Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 4):

what worked for me!

Disconnect your mobile from your mac and then visit

> Settings -> General > Profiles & Device management

option is available for me. But when I connect mobile with Xcode for testing its not there

Comment: disconnect device then this option will get available

Answer (score 1):

I saw it was there (Settings -> General) after I disconnected my iPhone from the computer. I didn't do anything!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the profile using Firefox and it never worked. When I download using Safari, the option started showing up. It seems the phone is not scanning the Firefox downloads folder for profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I am using iphone 8, it is running the ios version 14.2. I can install my react native ios app successfully, although the app will not open or launch after installation. my iphone device did not have the Profile and Device Management link under Settings.
I installed the profile patch from https://www.beta.apple.com/profile or you can follow this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0DwtJlP-AQ.
I then i connected the phone device again to the mac with my usb cable. building and running the app again from xcode 12, i faced the same issue.
However with my device connected and the app installed( although the app could not be launched ), i go to settings > General > Profile and Device Management is now visible and i can enable the trust setting. Go back and open the app the again and it will launch just fine.